# AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm very new at Python and I don't understand why this error occurs.
Here's the code I wrote :

```
var_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Vcond':[], 'Rsquared':[]})

for j in clim :
    varj = Cmean.loc[j][j]
    varz = Cmean.loc['Zi']['Zi']
    covzj = Cmean.loc['Zi'][j]
    B = np.linalg.inv(varj.to_numpy())
    Vcondj = varz-covzj @ B @ covzj
    Rsquared = (varz - Vcondj)/varz 
    var_1.loc[j]={'Vcond': Vcondj, 'Rsquared': Rsquared}

print(var_1)
```

And the error :

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'
```

My teacher said to use .to_numpy() this way to calculate the inverse of the matrix but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: hi. make sure to define all the names you use in your code snippet when asking a question here. for example, what's `Cmean`? see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more details

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I would like to define all the variables but Cmean is a DataFrame and it has been create with a lot of manipulations. I don't know how to write the final data frame as code in a short way...

Comment: In Python each object (variable) belongs to a specific class, with its own `methods`.  `to_numpy` is a method of a `pandas.DataFrame` (and `Series`).  `varj` is not one those, and does not have that method.  As a beginner, you'll encounter AttributeError like this often.  Try to understand what the variable actually is, and what is should be.  You should also learn to look up the language and module references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `df` dataframe that I have leftover from another question:

```
In [907]: type(df)                                                                                     
Out[907]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
In [908]: type(df.loc[1])                                                                              
Out[908]: pandas.core.series.Series
In [909]: type(df.loc[1][1])                                                                           
Out[909]: numpy.int64
```

See how successive `loc` indexing steps gives a `Series` and then a numeric value.

The `to_numpy` method of the dataframe produces a 2d array:

```
In [912]: df.to_numpy().shape                                                                          
Out[912]: (22, 2)
```

applied to the Series, we get a 1d array:

```
In [913]: df.loc[1].to_numpy()                                                                         
Out[913]: array([28, 13])
```

But as your error shows, that's it.  The np.float`object does not have a`to_numpy`method.  It already is a`numpy` object.

When writing code like this, you should know what kind of objects each step produces.  And be prepared to test that knowledge.  Bad guesses produce errors.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

`varj` seems to be of type `numpy.float64` so you can't convert it to a numpy datatype anymore. Since you mentioned that you want to use `to_numpy` in order to invert a matrix, you probably want to apply it to your dataframe instead.

Comment: Thank you ! The problem was that varj is a numpy.float64 type as you said, and I have to use .to_numpy for the next calculation with 2 variables. In this example, it was only with one variable... It was so ridiculous.